# HTML element statistics of the current page

Tags: open-source, html, firefox

Within Firefox, I’m looking for a way to show which HTML elements are used how many times on the current page.

It must display all used HTML elements (even invalid ones) and their count (→ sorted), e.g. like:

```
16 div 
13 span
 7 a
 5 p
 3 h1
 2 article
 2 h2
 1 body
 1 head
 1 html
 1 spoiler
```

It would be nice if it also takes elements removed/added by JavaScript into account; at best it should simply use the current DOM of when I start the tool.

I’d prefer an extension (displayed in the sidebar), but I’m open for other solutions (bookmarklet?). Displaying the list should not require more than a click or key combo.

A solution must be [FLOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software#FLOSS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Self-made solution

- Tested with Firefox and Chrome. IE doesn't work yet.
- It takes a live representation of the DOM into account
- Free and open-source (MIT license)

#### Screenshot

Do you need any prettier interface?

[image: Screenshot]

#### General

This is quite easy to achieve using a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker):

Source code as a GitHub Gist: https://gist.github.com/ComFreek/0ea3de26530f0d85ceb4

#### How to install

1. Go to http://subsimple.com/bookmarklets/jsbuilder.htm
2. Paste my code into the white text box
3. Change the bookmarklet's name
4. Click <kbd>compress</kbd>
5. Drag the link at the bottom of the page to your bookmark bar

#### Current source code

Better use the GitHub Gist link provided above. I'll always update there first. The code below is provided for the archive.

```
/**
 * A bookmarklet, which displays the number of occurrences of each HTML tag in the DOM
 * 
 * @author ComFreek
 * @license MIT
 * @link http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/10329/583
 */


function getTagCounts() {
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.documentElement, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);

    var tagCounts = {};
    while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
        var node = treeWalker.currentNode;
        if (!(node.tagName in tagCounts)) {
            tagCounts[node.tagName] = 0;
        }
        tagCounts[node.tagName]++;
    }
    return tagCounts;
}

function convToArray(tagCounts) {
    // to array
    var tags = [];

    for (var tagName in tagCounts) {
        if (tagCounts.hasOwnProperty(tagName)) {
            tags.push({tagName: tagName, count:  tagCounts[tagName]});
        }
    }
    return tags;
}

function sortCompareFn(tagA, tagB) {
    if (tagA.count > tagB.count) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (tagA.count < tagB.count) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function arrayToSimpleStr(tags) {
    // output
    var str = "";
    for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
        str += tags[i].tagName;
        str += ": ";
        str += tags[i].count;
        str += "\n";
    }
    return str;
}

var sortedTagCounts = convToArray(getTagCounts()).sort(sortCompareFn);
alert(arrayToSimpleStr(sortedTagCounts));
```

Answer (score 3):

Same as [@ComFreek's answer](/a/10329/185) but less code (and not sorted)

```
tags = {};
elems = document.querySelectorAll('*');
for(i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    if(tags[ elems[i].tagName ]) tags[ elems[i].tagName ]++;
    else tags[ elems[i].tagName ] = 1;
}
alert(JSON.stringify(tags,null,'\t'));
```

You can add this as an URL to your bookmarks:

```
javascript:tags={};elems=document.querySelectorAll('*');for(i=0;i<elems.length;i++){    if(tags[elems[i].tagName])tags[elems[i].tagName]++;else tags[elems[i].tagName]=1;}alert(JSON.stringify(tags,null,'\t'));
```

Comment: +1 The reason I chose `TreeWalker` was to leave the door open for counting comments and some other nodes which you won't find via `querySelectorAll()`.